# How to find references for a string (where it is being called) in Go binary

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, go

I have a Go binary and I have this string:

[image]

When I go to its location, with IDA Pro, and tries to find all the references (using `x`) I am getting a message that there are no references:

[image]

It might be because it is being load dynamically? If yes, is there a way to find the location statically?

Comment: Has the binary been fully analyzed at the time you try it? You should see a respective message in the log panel. Go binaries tend to be somewhat big and so it could take a while.

Comment: I verified it now and it was fully analyzed

Comment: Could you show the lines before? Perhaps it's a counted string type and the part you see isn't being (directly) referenced because the (I am just surmising here) containing struct starts _before_ this point ...